# How to use Eclipse to write JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Eclipse is totally new to me but I would like to write JavaScript code with it. I installed it and I don't have an option for `JavaScript` under `New Project`. There is also no `JavaScript` option in `Others`. Where can I find it?

Comment: Java and Javascript are entirely different things

Comment: I know but it doens't answer to my question

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers

Comment: @CharlottePanais the way you wrote it I didn't understood you knew the difference

Comment: Which Eclipse IDE package do you have? You might install JavaScript support first. There are old JavaScript support via [WTP](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and the new JavaScript support via [Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) (which requires NPM be installed). Only in the first case there is a _New_ dialog, in the second case you have to create a file with the extension `.js`.

Comment: @howlger `for JavaScript Eclipse embeds the language server of VS Code` then why not use VScode directly? :) If I had to write Java I would use Eclipse.

Comment: @JeremyThille Because of missing features in VS Code. VS Code may fit your needs, but not mine.

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you can follow:

1. Open your Eclipse IDE
2. Click File --> New (there you can see the folders)

From here we have 2 more options:

3. JavaScript > JavaScriptProject **OR** Web > Static Web Project
4. Add the name to your project and click Next
5. Finish

If you choose the Web Static Project for example you can

6. Click on the Java Tab on the top of your IDE (from there you can see the project)
7. Select your project folder and right click
8. New -- Others
9. There you can find your JS source file
10. Click next and name you JS-file (e.g. MyProject **.JS**)

Hope these steps where clear enough. In my personal preference if you want to write some JS code you can use the Visual Studio Code IDE which is the best for me. Have a great day.

Comment: The thing is that after istallation of Eclipse i cant see New JavaScript nor Web.

Comment: Hi @CharlottePanais, make sure that you have installed Java EE version of Eclipse in your system. Here you can find a package you could use aswell:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-06/r/eclipse-ide-web-and-javascript-developers-includes-incubating-components

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-06/r/eclipse-ide-web-and-javascript-developers-includes-incubating-components) package to write JavaScript code in Eclipse.

But with my JavaScript experience, I really don't recommend Eclipse for JavaScript development, the ones I use are [Atom](https://atom.github.io) by GitHub and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) by Microsoft.

Comment: The new JavaScript support via [Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) contains the VS Code language server. Thanks to LSP, only the UI differs.